# Test case getting failed after robolectric library updatded to 4.9.0 getting status code 403 from server: Forbidden

Tags: android, kotlin, robolectric, robolectric-gradle-plugin, robolectric-shadows

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugUnitTestKotlin'.

> Error while evaluating property 'filteredArgumentsMap' of task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugUnitTestKotlin'
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugUnitTestCompileClasspath'.
> > Could not resolve org.robolectric:robolectric:4.9.0.
> Required by:
> project :app
> > Could not resolve org.robolectric:robolectric:4.9.0.
> > Could not get resource 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/si-mobile-sdks/android/org/robolectric/robolectric/4.9.0/robolectric-4.9.0.pom'.
> > Could not GET 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/si-mobile-sdks/android/org/robolectric/robolectric/4.9.0/robolectric-4.9.0.pom'.
> Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

I have updated the robolectric library.
As the old library version giving unwanted test case failure as per suggetion updated it but after updating getting 403 error.

Expecting I should run as expected.

Quick suggestion really appreciated!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.